# Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet

Tags: database, mariadb

I logged into my adserver which i have been using for 70 days now, i even upgraded my mariadb to 5.5.46 on it but now i got an upgrade notice but it failed to upgrade, below is the message from terminal

Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.47+maria-1~trusty) ...
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                               [ OK ]
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                               [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-5.5 (= 5.5.47+maria-1~trusty); however                                                                                        :
  Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro                                                                                        r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-5.5
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the minimal Ubuntu install does not have everything that you need.

The post Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet provides the solution to your problem. I suggest you read that. However, I will provide a brief summary below.

Clean out the old mysql installation.

sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

Upgrade the things that are missing in the minimal Ubuntu installation.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Install MySql as normal:

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

If that still doesn't work you can do

sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken

Comment: Thanks for the tips. since i no longer use this setup, someone might find it useful

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the result of a muddled setup between installing `mariadb` and `mysql`. Rebooting the machine and running `apt-get` again solved the issue for me.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with the same software versions.

I had to run apt-get update / apt-get dist-upgrade, accept the failures, then reboot, then run both again. Now it's OK.

Also don't understand why the answer has been downvoted. It was a life saver for me.